# My Python if-else statements are not working and i can't figure out why

Tags: python, python-3.x

The 1st elif statement shows invalid syntax error

```
N = int(input())

arr = []
for i in range(0,N):
    inp = list(map(str,input().split()))
    if inp[0] == 'insert' :
        arr.insert(int(inp[1]),int(inp[2])
    if (inp[0] == 'print'):
        print(arr)
    if inp[0] == 'remove' :
        arr.remove(int(inp[1]))
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in the 7th line. You'd better use a linter

Comment: There are no `elif` statements in this code. Please post the actual code you're trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `)` in the 7th line. This should be:

```py
        arr.insert(int(inp[1]),int(inp[2]))
                                          ^
```

Use a linter in your IDE to flag those errors